# WinRM on Microsoft Azure on Ports other than 5985 and 5986

Tags: azure, winrm

I have searched long and hard for an answer to this one, but I cannot find it, and so I thought I would put it out there to everybody before I pull out what little there remains of my hair in frustration!

We have a number of Azure Windows Server 2012 R2 VMs, and they all belong to an availability set.  Traffic is routed to them using traffic manager, and so they can only be accessed by a VIP.  We want to be able to bring these Window servers into Server Manager, also a Server 2012 R2 installation, so that we can have visibility of these servers.

The default port is 5985, but the issue is, of course, that if we have more than one server in an availability set, then we would have to use a different NAT for each server.  So, my question, is there a way, pro-grammatically or systematically, to force server manager to connect to an Azure VM other than on the default ports 5985 or 5986?  Looking at it, I can't see a way, and that's fine if it cannot be done - we would simply assign a static public IP to those VMs - but if I can avoid doing that . . . :)

Any help will be very much appreciated!